# DIsable HUD for Some Applications

Tags: firefox, hud

I am using HUD on 12.04 ubuntu and firefox is crashing for me. I have similar results as per [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-firefox-extension/+bug/1027695). Another thing is that I have 0 addons on firefox, so this is not caused because of the addons.

Whenever I am using firefox and accidently touch the window key, it crashes the firefox. HUD does show options related to the firefox during this time.

So my question - Is it possible to hide and disable HUD for certain applications? I don't want to *disable entirely* as I am using it for other apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable HUD for Firefox by disabling the *Global Menu Bar Integration* add-on.
Go to *Tools > Add-ons > Global Menu Bar Integration* and disable it.However I think you were affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/globalmenu-extension/+bug/1025011) whose fix has been released in new Firefox versions.Please update your browser.